# Mage registry key "RID" already exists

Tags: magento-enterprise, permissions

This is on an (almost) fresh Magento EE 1.13.02 installation. I have only one custom module, which I disabled, however the error still occurs.

The issue happens in System -> Permissions -> Roles -> Click role to edit (/admin/permissions_role/editrole/rid/1/), and started happening since I added a second role.

After checking for a bit, I found the following blocks that were included, that contain the offending code:

```
// Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Api_Role_Grid_User
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $roleId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rid');
    Mage::register('RID', $roleId);
    // more code
```

And

```
// Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_Role_Grid_User
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $roleId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rid');
    Mage::register('RID', $roleId);
    // more code
```

These 2 blocks are almost identical, and both are included, causing the error in the title.

Does anyone know why this is happening ? A fix would be to move one of these files in local and perform a check for RID, but it's a very nasty sollution, so is there a better fix?

**Extra:** I do not have the module `Enhanced Admin Grids`

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the admin grid. I had the same issue in CE 1.9.

app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Type/Permissions/Role/User.php

> return ($type == 'adminhtml/permissions_role_grid_user');
>
> TO
>
> return (($type == 'adminhtml/permissions_role_grid_user') || ($type ==
> 'adminhtml/api_role_grid_user'));

[Admin Grids Breaks Magento SOAP/SML Roles #40](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/issues/40)

[fix SOAP/XML-RPC role page](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/commit/2c484d648de4781e8514d294fee5d5771eb70ec2)