# unable to login in admin it give error like `Role id 'G' already exists in the registry`

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise

I am trying to login to admin in commercial addition but it generate report like below.I have tried to disable compiler using include/config file nothing changed.can anyone please guide me on this.

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:42:"Role id 'G' already exists in the registry";i:1;s:2393:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Acl.php(160): Zend_Acl_Role_Registry->add(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Group), NULL)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Acl.php(100): Zend_Acl->addRole(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Group), NULL)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Acl.php(69): Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_Acl->loadRoles(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl), Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(98): Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_Acl->loadAcl()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(53): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('robert.b', 'acmRIjqHxz7Q4l0...', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1297): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1278): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(503): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(150): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(248): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(174): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(345): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(638): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/vhosts/cap-it.com/httpdocs/index.php(78): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Can this help you? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25717/mage-registry-key-rid-already-exists

Comment: no sorry that link is not solved my porblem :(